# Who coined ideals in Set Theory?

Tags: set-theory, ideals, math-history

One of the meanings of the word "ideal" in maths refers to Set Theory. Even though handbooks say that concept can be translated to Order Theory or to Algebra effortlessly, I am interested in:

1) Knowing which author was responsible for the introduction of ideals in Set Theory or in set-theoretic accounts, if you like it.

2) Get a grasp of the initial definition he or she provided.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend linking to previous related questions of yours: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1294560/264

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. Well, that link talks about ideals in number theory, but I am asking about their use in set theory......

Comment: I have already followed the track of those meanings in order theory or number theory. I need the explanation regarding set theory.

Comment: @Martin: Odd choice of tags, seeing it was you who added them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd say that some set theory-related tag belongs here. And adding both and leaving up to you which of them to use seems like a reliable way when in doubt.

Comment: Since ideals and filters are dual to each other, perhaps some information can also be found among questions tagged [math-history+filters](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history+filters).